# Wait for user input in a game while loop with Streamlit

Tags: python, game-development, streamlit

I'm coding up a game in streamlit, and the existing structure of my game sits within a
while loop. I take in user input, and then use that for other aspects of the game. When I run this in streamlit, it doesn't wait for the user to input, and rather goes on to the next part of the code. I have written up a small scale example of the structure of my game (my game is much to large to upload here). I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this issue?

I have tried using session states, but I don't really understand them all that well.  I have written up a small scale example of the structure of my game (my game is much to large to upload here). I was wondering if anyone could help me fix this issue? Here is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import time

game_over = False
game_night = False
game_day = True
votes = 0

while game_over == False:
    print(time.time())
    print(int(time.time()))
    if game_day:
        with st.form(key=str(time.time())):
            name = st.text_input(label='What is your name?')
            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')
        game_day = False
        game_night = True

    elif game_night:
        with st.form(key=str(time.time())):
            name = st.text_input(label='Who are you voting for?')
            submit_button = st.form_submit_button(label='Submit')
            votes += 1
        game_day = True
        game_night = False
    if votes == 5:
        game_over = True
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Consider checking that the text_input is not empty before moving on